# Alternative to xlrd, xlwt and xlutils in python

Tags: python

Are there any alternative to xlrd, xlwt and xlutils for handling MS Excel in python? As far as I know, their licensing does not allow it to be used for commercial purpose and I was wondering if there are any alternative to that other than using COM.

Comment: where is the restrictive license? see https://groups.google.com/group/python-excel/browse_thread/thread/1dd7e27327a5449f

Comment: I must have stumbled into the license for the tutorial as the person in the link is also confused about...Thanks.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that several of the xl* licenses have the advertising clause ('All advertising materials mentioning features or use of this software must display the following acknowledgment: "This product includes software developed by A B. C <x@y>."') which can cause headaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think openpyxl is worth a try:
http://packages.python.org/openpyxl/

Haven't used it myself, but is used in [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), a data analysis library.

Answer (score 1):

openpyxl is definitely worth a test drive, but keep in mind that it support only XLSX files,
while xlrd/xlwr support only XLS files.